# Convert text file from webscrape to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I want to convert a list from a webpage that I have scraped of into a dictionary. When scraping the list, I get a string of which the top 5 lines look like this when I open it. The text editor already jumps to a new line after eacht country:

Countries

ID / NAME

1 – Andorra

2 – Slovakia

3 – Austria

I want to make a dictionary where the numbers are the keys and the country names are the values. Does somebody have any advice on how to do this? The type of the list is a string still.

Many thanks,

Bram

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna take some guesses since your answer is not that clear.
Gonna assume that the string looks like this:

```
string = '\n1 - Andorra\n2 - Slovakia\n3 - Austria\n'
```

In case it's like this, you can do:

```
dictionary = dict()
for line in string.split("\n"):
    names = line.split(" - ")
    dictionary[names[0]] = names[1]
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you very much for your answer, it works. For some reason the split command does not accept " - ", but using " " and names[2] it works as well. Thanks again.I tried to make a list first, but the combination of a for loop and string.split is very elegant.